# Magento Layout Cache is saving the wrong template name

Tags: php, magento, caching, layout, magento-1.9

Magento has this cache called Layouts Cache (see attached image)

[image]
I have 2 themes A and B, i have module X enabled. In theme A i have X.xml in layouts folder, which reference to root of shipping method and change the template like this

```
<checkout_onepage_shippingmethod>
    <reference name='root'>
        <action method='setTemplate' ifconfig="X/X_config/enabled"><template>magentomod/X/checkout/onepage/shipping_method/available.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
</checkout_onepage_shippingmethod>
```

Theme B doesn't have that layout file, so it's using the old template, i cleared all the cache, started testing out theme A, came to shipping method, everything is working fine, but then i switch to theme B and shipping method is showing nothing, i checked inside `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php` and found out that the template name for checkout_onepage_shippingmethod is set to `magentomod/X/checkout/onepage/shipping_method/available.phtml` which is the custom template set for X module in theme A, but i didn't set it in theme B, so this template name must have been cached by magento cache above. I tried clearing the cache and B will work the way it should. But i cannot find a way to disable this type of behavior, i also tried adding disabling cache to the layout file but it still doesn't stop it from doing that, and in X layout there are several other blocks that are setting templates this way but i'm not having problems with those other blocks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found out that was because someone used setCacheKey to a specific value in a layout file